# How to get second to last index in a list in Jinja?

Tags: html, jinja2

```
{% for value in values %}
     {{ value }}
      {% if loop.index < values|length %}
        --->
      <% endif %>
<% endfor %>
```

For examples, if:

```
values = [1, 2, 3]
```

when the iteration gets to 2, I want to display --->, but the:

```
if loop.index < values|length
```

will arrive at 3. I tried:

```
if loop.index < values|length-1
```

But it didn't work.  The html display I want is:

```
1
--->
2
--->
3
```

As you can see, after '3', I don't want --->.

Comment: If you only want to do it at the second to last position you should be checking index == length - 1 (or index0 == length - 2). Not < ...

Comment: Also "it didn't work" isn't very much to go on. Didn't work ... _how_?

Comment: ‘didn't work’ means for the last element 3, it also output '--->', which I don't want

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Please see my edit.

Comment: You do have `values|length`, not _value_, right? you're checking the length of your list, values (with an s) and not value like you show in your question?

Comment: That's my typo. I corrected. The real question is how to check the 'second to last' index? 'values|length-1' doesn't work.

Comment: That is the second to last; print it and you'll see.